# Concatenate column values in Pandas DataFrame replacing “NaN” values with comma

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to concatenate Pandas DataFrame columns replacing “NaN” values with comma.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ["1","2","3","4","5",np.nan],
                   'col2'  : ["p1","p2","p1",np.nan,"p2",np.nan], 
                   'col3' : ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]})


df


 col1    col2  col3
0    1    p1    A
1    2    p2    B
2    3    p1    C
3    4    NaN   D
4    5    p2    E
5    NaN  NaN   F
```

I need a output :-

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0    1    p1    A    1, p1, A
1    2    p2    B    2, p2, B
2    3    p1    C    3, p1, C
3    4    NaN   D    4, , D
4    5    p2    E    5, p2, E
5    NaN  NaN   F     , , F
```

Basically I need equal number of commas for each row in `col4`.

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace missing values by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), then use `join` per rows:

```
df['col4'] = df.astype(str).fillna('').apply(', '.join, axis=1)
```

Or add `,` and use `sum` for join, last remove last `,` by [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html):

```
df['col4'] = df.astype(str).fillna('').add(', ').sum(axis=1).str.rstrip(', ')
```

Or processing each column separately:

```
df['col4'] = (df['col1'].astype(str).fillna('') + ', ' + 
              df['col2'].astype(str).fillna('') + ', ' + 
              df['col3'].astype(str))
```

---

```
print (df)
  col1 col2 col3      col4
0    1   p1    A  1, p1, A
1    2   p2    B  2, p2, B
2    3   p1    C  3, p1, C
3    4  NaN    D    4, , D
4    5   p2    E  5, p2, E
5  NaN  NaN    F     , , F
```